# How to create separate dicts from dicts inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list containing several dicts. I want to store each of these dicts in a separate variable.

The data is something like:

```
my_list = [{'key': 'value'}, {'key' : 'value'}]
```

I have tried the following code.

```py
for i in range(len(data)):
    string = 'ticket' + str(i)
    exec('eval(string) = data[i]')
```

However, when I run the code, it gives me the error can't assign to function call. Is there any way to get it to  evaluate string and assign to that? I want it to execute something like this:

```py
ticket1 = data[1]
```

Comment: Can you show us how your list looks like, also a better approach is convert the list of dicts to dict of dicts

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach is to have a dictionary of dictionaries

```
#List of dictionaries
my_list = [{'key': 'value'}, {'key' : 'value'}]

#Dictionary of dictionaries
dct = {'data_{}'.format(idx): item for idx, item in enumerate(my_list)}

print(dct)

#Use keys to access inner dictionary
print(dct['data_0'])
```

The output will be

```
{'data_0': {'a': 1}, 'data_1': {'b': 2}}
{'a': 1}
```